# In Xamarin.Forms, all of my click events stopped working after I added a ScrollView to the page. Is the ScrollView intercepting the clicks?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Here's the relevant code in question:

XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="ContentPage_MainPage"
             x:Class="OpenBacon.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Subreddits" Order="Primary" Priority="10" Text="Initializing...." Clicked="ToolbarItemSubreddits_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Spacer" Order="Primary" Priority="20" Text="     " />
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="30" Clicked="ToolbarItemSearch_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconSearch" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Mail" Order="Primary" Priority="40" Clicked="ToolbarItemMail_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconMail" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="50" Clicked="ToolbarItemBaconButton_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconBaconButton" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ScrollView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ScrollView_Main" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout_Main">
                    <!-- Sort bar. -->
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2" x:Name="Label_PostsSinceLastRefresh" />
                            <Button x:Name="ButtonSort" Grid.Column="1" Text="" FontSize="Small" Clicked="ButtonSort_Clicked" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- Posts list goes here (generated). -->
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="StackLayout_Posts">

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

C#:

*(In the constructor for MainPage)*

```cs
Content = ScrollView_Main;
```

If I comment out the "Content =" line, the ScrollView is gone but all the toolbar items are able to receive their click events again.  Uncommented, the scrolling works perfectly but I can't tap anything on the page.

I can't find any mention of any options to fix this behavior.  Is this a Xamarin.Forms bug or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**  Here's the full XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="ContentPage_MainPage"
             x:Class="OpenBacon.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Subreddits" Order="Primary" Priority="10" Text="Initializing...." Clicked="ToolbarItemSubreddits_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Spacer" Order="Primary" Priority="20" Text="     " />
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="30" Clicked="ToolbarItemSearch_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconSearch" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Mail" Order="Primary" Priority="40" Clicked="ToolbarItemMail_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconMail" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="50" Clicked="ToolbarItemBaconButton_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconBaconButton" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ScrollView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ScrollView_Main" Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout_Main">
                    <!-- Sort bar. -->
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2" x:Name="Label_PostsSinceLastRefresh" />
                            <Button x:Name="ButtonSort" Grid.Column="1" Text="" FontSize="Small" Clicked="ButtonSort_Clicked" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- Posts list goes here (generated). -->
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="StackLayout_Posts">

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <ContentView x:Name="Popup_Subreddits" BackgroundColor="DimGray" Padding="10, 10" IsVisible="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Subreddits" ItemTapped="ListView_Subreddits_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}"></x:Array>
                            </ListView.ItemsSource>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_Subreddits_OutClick" />
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView x:Name="Popup_BaconButton" BackgroundColor="#446"  Padding="75, 0, 0, 75" IsVisible="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, .9, .9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="600" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="#0079D3">
                        <ListView x:Name="ListView_BaconButton" ItemTapped="ListView_BaconButton_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSrc}" TextColor="White" DetailColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_BaconButton_OutClick" />
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/373736/#Comment_373736

Apparently, all I needed to do was add the following to the ScrollView definition:

**AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"**

**AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"**

I.e.

```xml
<ScrollView 
    x:FieldModifier="public" 
    x:Name="ScrollView_Main" 
    Orientation="Vertical" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
```

So the full XAML now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="ContentPage_MainPage"
             x:Class="OpenBacon.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Subreddits" Order="Primary" Priority="10" Text="Initializing...." Clicked="ToolbarItemSubreddits_Clicked" />
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Spacer" Order="Primary" Priority="20" Text="     " />
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="30" Clicked="ToolbarItemSearch_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconSearch" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Mail" Order="Primary" Priority="40" Clicked="ToolbarItemMail_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconMail" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="50" Clicked="ToolbarItemBaconButton_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconBaconButton" />
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ScrollView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ScrollView_Main" Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout_Main">
                    <!-- Sort bar. -->
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2" x:Name="Label_PostsSinceLastRefresh" />
                            <Button x:Name="ButtonSort" Grid.Column="1" Text="" FontSize="Small" Clicked="ButtonSort_Clicked" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <!-- Posts list goes here (generated). -->
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="StackLayout_Posts">

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <ContentView x:Name="Popup_Subreddits" BackgroundColor="DimGray" Padding="10, 10" IsVisible="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
                        <ListView x:Name="ListView_Subreddits" ItemTapped="ListView_Subreddits_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}"></x:Array>
                            </ListView.ItemsSource>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_Subreddits_OutClick" />
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            </ContentView>
            <ContentView x:Name="Popup_BaconButton" BackgroundColor="#446"  Padding="75, 0, 0, 75" IsVisible="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, .9, .9" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="600" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="#0079D3">
                        <ListView x:Name="ListView_BaconButton" ItemTapped="ListView_BaconButton_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSrc}" TextColor="White" DetailColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_BaconButton_OutClick" />
                </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, it's identical to the code in my question with the exception of those two attributes being added to the ScrollView definition.  That fixed everything.

Here are some screenshots of how it looks now:

[image: Screenshot #1]

[image: Screenshot #2]

[image: Screenshot #3 (code modified slightly)]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is the `AbsoluteLayout` that you have above your `ScrollView`.

When not given any LayoutFlags and LayoutOptions it takes up the whole available space which is causing it to take the whole screen. When you add the `ScrollView` it takes over the whole screen which is somehow intercepting the events. What I would suggest you do is remove this `AbsoluteLayout` as I do not see any specific use for it anyway so your layout would look something like:

```
<ScrollView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ScrollView_Main" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout_Main">
                <!-- Sort bar. -->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2" x:Name="Label_PostsSinceLastRefresh" />
                        <Button x:Name="ButtonSort" Grid.Column="1" Text="" FontSize="Small" Clicked="ButtonSort_Clicked" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <!-- Posts list goes here (generated). -->
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="StackLayout_Posts">

                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work because I also have some hidden ContentViews for the popups and removing the AbsoluteLayout block caused it to throw a "The property 'Content' is set more than once" error.  I tried then encompassing it in a StackLayout instead but then the click events still don't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: I updated the question to include the entire MainPage.xaml contents.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try using the StackLayout that is inside the ScrollView instead of creating it outside may be?

Comment: I tried replacing the AbsoluteLayout with the StackLayout.  That solved the click intercept and scrolling issues, but without the AbsoluteLayout, my popup menus are now being displayed at the very bottom of the screen, whereas I need them to be overlayed for this to work.

Is there a way for me to accomplish this without an AbsoluteLayout?  If not, is there at least a way to get the AbsoluteLayout to not disable scrolling or intercept click events?

Comment: Can you try using RelativeLayout instead may be?

Comment: Trying that, but so far it's not going well.  The scrolling cuts off now and the menus display relative to the top of the scrollview instead of relative to the screen or toolbar.  It's starting to look like RelativeLayout may not be an option.  I can't believe it's so difficult to get an absolute-positioned view to display on top of a scroll view!  It shouldn't be so hard to do something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` to achieve this.

I created simple demo to simulate your function,and  in order to make it easier to understand, I turned the background yellow.
The main code is:

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Subreddits" Order="Primary" Priority="10" Text="Initializing...." Clicked="ToolbarItemSubreddits_Clicked"/>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Spacer" Order="Primary" Priority="20" Text="     " />
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="30" Clicked="ToolbarItemSearch_Clicked">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconSearch" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="ToolbarItem_Mail" Order="Primary" Priority="40" Clicked="ToolbarItemMail_Clicked">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconMail" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="50" Clicked="ToolbarItemBaconButton_Clicked">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"  Android="OpenBaconBaconButton" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ScrollView_Main" Orientation="Vertical">   
       <!--attention here-->
        <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="800" WidthRequest="800" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout_Main"  HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0}" >
                <!-- Sort bar. -->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="test" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2" x:Name="Label_PostsSinceLastRefresh" />
                        <Button x:Name="ButtonSort" Grid.Column="1" Text="Button_Sort" FontSize="Small" Clicked="ButtonSort_Clicked" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <!-- Posts list goes here (generated). -->
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="StackLayout_Posts">

                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

        <ContentView x:Name="Popup_Subreddits" BackgroundColor="DimGray" Padding="10, 10" IsVisible="True" 
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0.06}"
                     >
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <ListView x:Name="ListView_Subreddits" ItemTapped="ListView_Subreddits_ItemTapped">
                        <ListView.ItemsSource>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>mono</x:String>
                            <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                            <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                            <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                            <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                            <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                            <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                            <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                            <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                           </x:Array>
                        </ListView.ItemsSource>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_Subreddits_OutClick" />
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>
         <ContentView x:Name="Popup_BaconButton" BackgroundColor="#446"  Padding="0, 0, 0, 0" IsVisible="False" 
                      RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0.06}"
                      >
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="600" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="#0079D3">
                    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTapped="ListView_BaconButton_ItemTapped"> 
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Comment}"  ImageSource="{Binding Image}" TextColor="White" DetailColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Popup_BaconButton_OutClick" />
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Note：

1.use `RelativeLayout` as the parent layout.And set the property of the `ContentView` just like this:

```
<ContentView x:Name="Popup_Subreddits" BackgroundColor="DimGray" Padding="10, 10" IsVisible="True" 
                     RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0.06}"
                     >
 </ContentView>
```

And

```
  <ContentView x:Name="Popup_BaconButton" BackgroundColor="#446"  Padding="0, 0, 0, 0" IsVisible="False" 
                      RelativeLayout.XConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = 0}"
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = 0.06}"
                      >
</ContentView>
```

Of course, you can adjust the value of `Factor` according to your requirement.

The result of the demo is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIv2X.jpg)
[image]

Comment: We're close!  However, when I scroll the main view down (looking through new posts), the scrolling cuts off at a certain point and I can't go down any further (wasn't like this before).  Also, if I scroll down and then tap one of the menus, it displays at the top of the scroll list and I have to scroll back up to see it all.

Comment: You can adjust the ' Factor' of 'RelativeLayout.XConstraint'.e.g.' 0.3'.

Comment: How would that have any effect on the scrolling getting cut-off or the menus not displaying in the right place?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's beginning to look like RelativeView is not a viable solution because there's no way to get it to display in the same place relative to the toolbar regardless of where we are in the vertical scroll.  With this solution, if I scroll down a ways and then tap the button, the popup menu appears at the top of the scrollview, which means I have to scroll all the way back up to see it.  That's obviously not usable.  I need this to overlay, which is why I went with an AbsoluteLayout in the first place, except that breaks the scrolling altogether.  Frustrating....